# Insert Ignore - is there way to know if statement was ignored? MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT IGNORE .....";


if(mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error()))
{
      //code to execute
}
```

I want to execute code if the row is inserted.  Is there some time of value that can be returned that would tell me if the statement was inserted or ignored?

**Edit:  Right now, "code to execute" always executes - even on ignore instances**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

mysql_affected_rows() will return 1 or 0, 1 if the insert took place

```
if(mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error()))
{
      if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1){
       //insert took place
       }else{
       //no insert
       }


}
```

Comment: Thanks - accepted this answer.  Quick question - doesn't matter if the mysql_query is in an if statement, correct?  - since it will go through every time.

Comment: if(mysql_query that only check if the statement runs\ is valid, wont tell you insert vs ignore

Comment: Need to ask something, is there any other instance except duplicate primary key situation when affected rows will return zero ? Or evey case of 0 affected rows in this case be considered that of a duplicate primary key ?

Comment: ref.: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

for PDO, answer will be

```
$query="insert ignore into ...;";
$statement=$link->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
if($statement->rowCount()==1){
   //insert confirmed;
}else{
   //ignore confirmed;
}
```